# Does 20th Century Fox still get any royalties from the Star Wars franchise?

Tags: star-wars, 20th-century-fox

The first six *Star Wars* movies were financed, distributed, and marketed by the studio 20th Century Fox.  In return, Fox earned the net profits of the films.  After the production company Lucasfilm was sold to Disney in 2012, future films are now financed, distributed, and marketed by Disney.  The profits now go to Disney.

**Which** (if any) **current or future activities of the *Star Wars* franchise would still earn royalties for 20th Century Fox?**  Some activities to consider:

- Presentation of the original 6 movies in a movie theater after the 2012 sale
- Television broadcasts of the original 6 movies after 2012
- Re-broadcast of Star Wars TV shows/series
- Releases of the original 6 movies in pre-2012 formats (VHS, DVD, Blu-Ray)
- Releases of the original 6 movies in new formats (e.g. Netflix)
- Future "special editions" of the original 6 movies
- Merchandise licensed prior to 2012 (e.g. books, toys) that was sold after 2012
- Anything created with Disney's involvement (here for completeness; I highly doubt it)

Also, if Fox's rights expire before the copyright runs out, that would be helpful to note.

Comment: What research have you done because this article covers everything: https://screenrant.com/star-wars-movie-tv-rights-explained/

Comment: @Legion600 the article talks about rights, not royalties. However, this is all likely moot since Disney will complete the merger process with 20th Century Fox and pretty much own all rights and royalties.